# How do I set a default for a timestamp column in mysql

Tags: mysql, alter

I have a column, "posted", which is a timestamp column.  I want it to be auto populated with the current date time.

When I attempt to modify the column with...

```
alter table results alter column posted set default current_timestamp;
```

> I get the following response: [42000][1064] You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'current_timestamp' at line
>   1.

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.29

Comment: In mysql it's modify column isn't it?

Comment: modify column and alter column both return the error